# sqlalchemy delete function problem, I want to delete a single item, but it actually deletes the whole category?

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, flask, sqlalchemy

[this is my github link](https://github.com/arrickx/Item-Catalog-Application)

I'm using sqlalchemy for this project.

Everything except the delete function runs well for the CRUD.

just want to wondering what happen?

```
# Edit the specific item
@app.route('/catalog/<int:categories_id>/<int:items_id>/edit',
           methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def editItem(categories_id, items_id):
    editedItem = session.query(CategoryItem).filter_by(id=items_id).one()
...
    if request.method == 'POST':
...
        session.add(editedItem)
        session.commit()
        flash("item edited successfully!")
        return redirect(url_for('showItem', categories_id=categories_id,
                                items_id=items_id))
    else:
        return render_template('edititem.html', categories_id=categories_id,
                               items_id=items_id, item=editedItem)


# Delete the specific item
@app.route('/catalog/<int:categories_id>/<int:items_id>/delete',
           methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def deleteItem(categories_id, items_id):
    itemToDelete = session.query(CategoryItem).filter_by(id=items_id).one()
...
    if request.method == 'POST':
        session.delete(itemToDelete)
        session.commit()
        flash("item deleted successfully!")
        return redirect(url_for('showCategories', categories_id=categories_id))
    else:
        return render_template('deleteitem.html', categories_id=categories_id,
                               items_id=items_id, item=itemToDelete)
```

as you can see in the code.

Both **editedItem and deleteItem** are using **session.query(CategoryItem).filter_by(id=items_id).one()**

But when I delete the item.

instead of the single item got deleted, the whole category was deleted.

Please see the template below

```
<form action="{{url_for('deleteItem' ,categories_id=categories_id, items_id=items_id, item=itemToDelete)}}" method="POST">&nbsp
  <input type="submit" value ="Delete">
  <a href = "{{url_for('showItem',categories_id=categories_id, items_id=items_id)}}"><button type="button">Cancel</button></a>
```

I'm not sure what caused this problem.

Comment: Give us a minimal working example and not a advertising GitHub link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you set your relationship with cascade `delete-orphan`.

```
class Categories(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'categories'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(250), nullable=False)
    user_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('user.id'))
    user = relationship(User)

    @property
    def serialize(self):
        return {
            'name': self.name,
            'id': self.id,
        }


class CategoryItem(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'category_item'
    name = Column(String(80), nullable=False)
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    description = Column(String(250))
    categories_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('categories.id'))
    categories = relationship(Categories, cascade="all, delete-orphan",
                              single_parent=True)
    user_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('user.id'))
    user = relationship(User)

    @property
    def serialize(self):
        return {
            'name': self.name,
            'description': self.description,
            'id': self.id,
        }
```

Your CategoryItem table is the parent table. You are setting a relationship inside it with Categories as a Child object. When you have `cascage='delete-orphan'` this includes cascade deletes but with added behavior (you can read more about it here: http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/cascades.html#delete)

Try to remove `delete-orphan` from your cascade argument

Comment: Thanks. I found that working if I remove the whole thing. "cascade="all, delete-orphan"" after remove all of it. it work!

Comment: Awesome happy I was able to help